# What is the difference between object and instance?

Tags: language-agnostic, oop, programming-languages

I'd like to know the difference between object and instance of class. I feel both are same, but why do we call with two names. Can anybody explain with real life example?

Comment: Unfortunately, the majority of these answers are wrong. So read them all.

Comment: @Evan Carroll - I think I see your point, but it would depend on the language would it not? Is it fair to say that `instance` is a subset of `object`?

Comment: @Pascal replacing "java" tag with "language-agnostic" added a new level of complexity to this question. Unfortunately, most answers don't live up to that complexity. See comments to Bill's answer for instance.

Answer (score 9):

They are the same thing in most object-oriented languages.  "Instance of a class" is just how the term "object" is defined.

Comment: No it isn't. Otherwise javascript and all other class-less languages (lua, etc.) would not have objects. And, they do. See Dario's answer for the most-right answer here.

Comment: @Evan Carroll: Check the edit history of the question.  It had the `java` tag when I answered.

Answer (score 5):

*(Edit: This question originally had the "java" tag. Thus language without classes were out of scope.)*

**Object**

> A pattern (exemplar) of a class. The
>   class Dog defines all possible dogs by
>   listing the characteristics and
>   behaviors they can have; the object
>   Lassie is one particular dog, with
>   particular versions of the
>   characteristics. A Dog has fur; Lassie
>   has brown-and-white fur.

**Instance**

> One can have an instance of a class;
>   the instance is the actual object
>   created at runtime. In programmer
>   jargon, the Lassie object is an
>   instance of the Dog class. The set of
>   values of the attributes of a
>   particular object is called its state.
>   The object consists of state and the
>   behaviour that's defined in the
>   object's class.

([Wikipedia, Object-oriented programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming))

Answer (score 5):

Just for the sake of completeness: *In [prototype-based programming languages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prototype-based_programming), no distinctions between classes and instances/objects are drawn*.

Let's step back if you're asking this question chances are you only know of class-based object orientation. It kinda works like this.

1. `Class` tells you what you want to have (data schema), and how you want to operate on it (methods).
2. Create an `Object` fill it in with what it needs (data), and use the operations defined with it.

However, you don't need a `Class` to have an object if you can find a different way to answer the question *what do you want to my object to do and how*. In an alternative model called called *prototype object orientation* instances are created by cloning existing ones (prototypes) and replicating and extending the behavior of the clone. The objects have no schema to follow in this format. They're just a grouping of data and stuff that acts on the data.

Comment: This is essential to understanding the question and was excluded from the other answers. I think if your answer grew in substance a little bit more you would be the obvious winner. The majority of these answers are wrong or way off. I was right about to post this reference too. You can only instantiate a non-object. It wouldn't make sense to say A is an instance of A and A is an object - yet, we say A is an instance of B and B is class.

Answer (score 4):

"object", "class object" and "instance" terms has only historical distinctions. Currently there is even one article in Wiki for all of this:)

Here additional proofs, that terms "object" and "instance" are quals (from "Object-Oriented Software Construction" by Bertran Meyer):

*An object belonging to the set of objects described by an ADT specification is called an instance of the ADT. For example, a specific stack which satisfies the properties of the STACK abstract data type will be an instance of STACK.*

*Like an ADT, a class is a type: it describes a set of possible data structures, called
the instances of the class. Abstract data types too have instances; the difference is that an
instance of an ADT is a purely mathematical element (a member of some mathematical
set), whereas an instance of a class is a data structure that may be represented in the
memory of a computer and manipulated by a software system.*

*The definition of **“class” yields as a byproduct a definition of “object”. An object is
simply an instance of some class**. For example an instance of class STACK — a data
structure representing a particular stack — is an object; so is an instance of class POINT,
representing a particular point in two-dimensional space.*

Answer (score 3):

They are the same. In context, "instance" emphasizes the fact that it is an instantiation of the class definition; "object" emphasizes the fact that it is a unique entity.

Answer (score 2):

They are practically the same in this context. "Object" may be used as a slightly more general / vague term, "instance" is typically used more specifically as "instance of a class".

Answer (score 2):

An object is a more general term. C uses the term object, even though it doesn't have classes at all -- from its viewpoint, any variable (for example) is an object.

A few object oriented languages don't have classes either. A class is a way of specifying the properties of objects; all the objects of a given class share those properties. In some languages (e.g., Javascript, Self), however, you don't have to specify those properties in a class. Rather, start with one object (the "exemplar") from which you clone a new object and modify it as you see fit. When/if you create a number of objects without modifying them, you can end up with a "class" in a manner of speaking (objects with the same properties), but that's more or less an accident.

Answer (score 1):

Same thing: an "object" is really "an instance of a class".

Answer (score 1):

I can illustrate this best with python, so here goes:
In Python you can create a class. Lets call it the `Person` class. Then you create an *instance* of the `Person` class. Lets call him Bob. So `bob = Person()`. The thing is, both `bob` and `Person` are objects. When you do `Person()`, you're actually calling the constructor on the `Person` *class* object, which gives you an *instance* object - namely `bob`.

Comment: And to add to the fun -- Person the class is also an object.  :)

Answer (score 1):

You use *instance* when you want to highlight that an object is created from a given type or class.

See this paragraph on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_(computer_science)#Object-oriented_languages):

> In a language where each object is created from a class, an object is called an instance of that class. If each object has a type, two objects with the same class would have the same datatype. Creating an instance of a class is sometimes referred to as instantiating the class.
>
> A real-world example of an object would be "my dog", which is an instance of a type (a class) called "dog", which is a subclass of a class "animal".

Comment: +1. Everyone else is saying "an object is an instance of a class," which is true; but they are also saying, "so they are the same thing."  Not quite.  *of a class* tells us that "instance" has relationship connotations that are absent from "object", even though every object *is* an instantiation of one (or, in some languages, more) class(es).

Comment: Actually that isn't true. Some languages implement Objects without classes.

Comment: @evan "in a language where each object is created from a class"