# Difference between object and instance

Tags: oop

I know this sort of question has been [asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2290422/what-is-the-difference-between-object-and-instance) [before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1215881/the-difference-between-classes-objects-and-instances), but I still feel that the answer is too ambiguous for me (and, by extension, some/most beginners) to grasp.

I have been trying to teach myself broader concepts of programming than procedural and basic OOP.  I understand the concrete concepts of OOP (you make a class that has data (members) and functions (methods) and then instantiate that class at run time to actually do stuff, that kind of thing).

I think I have a handle on what a class is (*sort of a design blueprint for an instance to be created in its likeness at compile time*).  But if that's the case, what is an object?  I also know that in prototype based languages, this can muck things up even more, but perhaps this is why there needs to be a clear distinction between object and instance in my mind.

Beyond that, I struggle with the concepts of "object" and "instance".  A lot of resources that I read (including answers at SO) say that they are largely the same and that the difference is in semantics.  Other people say that there is a true conceptual difference between the two.

Can the experts here at SO help a beginner have that "aha" moment to move forward in the world of OOP?

Note: this isn't homework, I don't go to school - however, I think it would help people that are looking for homework help.

Comment: I wonder if you would like to add some additional questions like, "are all instances objects?" , and, "are all objects instances?" If both "yes", then we can confirm that they are the same.

Comment: Once you instantiate a class (using new), that instantiated thing becomes an object. An object is something that can adhere to encapsulation, polymorphism, abstraction principles of object oriented programming and the real thing a program interacts with to consume the instance members defined in class. Object contains instance members (non-static members).

Thus instance of a class is an object. The word ‘instance’ is used when you are referring to the origin from where it born, it's more clearer if you say ‘instance of a class’ compared to ‘object of a class’

Answer (score 141, accepted):

A blueprint for a house design is like a class description.  All the houses built from that blueprint are objects of that class.  A given house is an instance.

Comment: Also, there's a street from my hometown that has a little bit of local fame because there are 8 identically built brick houses in a row (before the concept of "housing development" came into being).  So I can visualize that very nicely.  "Class" is what the architect drew up.  The finished houses are "objects" because they're all identically built.  Each house is an "instance" because they have (and can continue to be) all treated differently since then [now one has siding :o( ].

Comment: And Static Methods are like the utilities that all the houses share.

Comment: But isn't a house built from the blueprint an instance?

Comment: It means, the first memories occupy by the class definition is instance. while all the objects which are created are called objects.

Comment: Isn't object and instance exactly same ?

Comment: Awesome. I like your answer. I have the same problem and want to ask here until I find your answer.

Comment: I really like this description and using houses is a great way to teach it. However I don't fully understand the difference between an object and an instance. If objects are houses then wouldn't an object be a house, making an object the same as an instance?

Comment: @Lewis Black, no worries, the difference is so subtle that in 99% of the cases doesn't really matter (it makes a bit of sense when you use inheritance or polimorphism, and want to distinguish between the possible classes an object on memory could belong to). Some of the answers below try to explain the difference, but most *confuse the concept of instance and reference*; a reference would be the postal address (Dundas St 54) to a house which several people can have. In a computer the memory address correponds to physical memory address.

Comment: What do you mean by 'given house'?

Answer (score 45):

The truth is that object oriented programming often creates confusion by creating a disconnect between the philosophical side of development and the actual mechanical workings of the computer. I'll try to contrast the two for you:

The basic concept of OOP is this: Class >> Object >> Instance.

The class = the blue print.
The Object is an actual thing that is built based on the 'blue print' (like the house).
An instance is a virtual copy (but not a real copy) of the object.

The more technical explanation of an 'instance' is that it is a 'memory reference' or a reference variable. This means that an 'instance' is a variable in memory that *only* has a memory address of an object in it. The object it addresses is the same object the instance is said to be 'an instance of'. If you have many instances of an object, you really just have many variables in difference places in your memory that all have the same exact memory address in it - which are all the address of the same exact object. You can't ever 'change' an instance, although it looks like you can in your code. What you really do when you 'change' an instance is you change the original object directly. Electronically, the processor goes through one extra place in memory (the reference variable/instance) before it changes the data of the original object.

The process is: processor >> memory location of instance >> memory location of original object.

Note that it doesn't matter which instance you use - the end result will always be the same. ALL the instances will continue to maintain the same exact information in their memory locations - the object's memory address - and only the object will change.

The relationship between class and object is a bit more confusing, although philosophically its the easiest to understand (blue print >> house). If the object is actual data that is held somewhere in memory, what is 'class'? It turns out that mechanically the object is an exact copy of the class. So the class is just another variable somewhere else in memory that holds the same exact information that the object does. Note the difference between the relationships:

Object is a *copy* of the class.
Instance is a variable that holds the memory address of the object.

You can also have multiple objects of the same class and then multiple instances of each of those objects. In these cases, each object's set of instances are equivalent in value, but the instances between objects are not. For example:

Let Class A
From Class A let Object1, Object2, and Object3.

//Object1 has the same exact value as object2 and object3, but are in different places in memory.

from Object1>> let obj1_Instance1, obj1_Instace2 , obj1_Instance3

//all of these instances are also equivalent in value and in different places in memory. Their values = Object1.MemoryAddress.

etc.

Things get messier when you start introducing types. Here's an example using types from c#:

//assume class Person exists
Person john = new Person();

Actually, this code is easier to analyze if you break it down into two parts:

```
Person john;
john = new Person();
```

In technical speak, the first line 'declares a variable of *type* Person. But what does that mean?? The general explanation is that I now have an empty variable that can only hold a Person object. But wait a minute - its an empty variable! There is nothing in that variables memory location. It turns out that 'types' are mechanically meaningless. Types were originally invented as a way to manage data and nothing else. Even when you declare primitive types such as int, str, chr (w/o initializing it), nothing happens within the computer. This weird syntactical aspect of programming is part of where people get the idea that classes are the blueprint of objects. OOP's have gotten even more confusing with types with delegate types, event handlers, etc. I would try not focus on them too much and just remember that they are all a misnomer. Nothing changes with the variable until its either becomes an object or is set to a memory address of an object.

The second line is also a bit confusing because it does two things at once:

The right side "new Person()" is evaluated first. It creates a new copy of the Person class - that is, it creates a new object.

The left side "john =", is then evaluated after that. It turns john into a reference variable giving it the memory address of the object that was just created on the right side of the same line.

If you want to become a good developer, its important to understand that no computer environment ever works based on philosophic ideals. Computers aren't even that logical - they're really just a big collection of wires that are glued together using basic boolean circuits (mostly NAND and OR).

Answer (score 36):

The word **Class** comes from **Classification** (*A **Category** into which something is put*), Now we have all heard that a **Class** is like a Blueprint,but what does this exactly mean ? It means that the **Class** holds a Description of a particular Category ,(*I would like to show the difference between Class , Object and Instance with example using Java and I would request the readers to visualise it like a Story while reading it , and if you are not familiar with java doesn't matter*) So let us start with make a **Category** called **HumanBeing** , so the Java program will expressed it as follows

```
class HumanBeing{ 
   /*We will slowly build this category*/ 
}
```

Now what attributes does a **HumanBeing** have in general **Name**,**Age**,**Height**,**Weight** for now let us limit our self to these four attributes, let us add it to our Category

```
class HumanBeing{
    private String Name;
    private int Age;
    private float Height;
    private float Weight; 

   /*We still need to add methods*/

}
```

Now every category has a behaviour for example category **Dog** has a behaviour to bark,fetch,roll etc... , Similarly our category **HumanBeing** can also have certain behaviour,for example when we ask our **HumanBeing** what is your name/age/weight/height? It should give us its name/age/weight/height, so in java we do it as follows

```
class HumanBeing{
    private String Name;
    private int Age;
    private float Height;
    private float Weight;  

    public HumanBeing(String Name,int Age,float Height,float Weight){
       this.Name = Name;
       this.Age  = Age;
       this.Height = Height;
       this.Weight = Weight;
    }

    public String getName(){
      return this.Name;
    }

    public int getAge(){
      return this.age;
    }

    public float getHeight(){
      return this.Height;
    }

    public float getWeight(){
      return this.Weight;
    }
}
```

Now we have added behaviour to our category **HumanBeing**,so we can ask for its name ,age ,height ,weight but whom will you ask these details from , because `class HumanBeing` is just a category , it is a blueprint for example an Architect makes a blueprint on a paper of the building he wants to build , now we cannot go on live in the blueprint(*its description of the building*) we can only live in the building once it is built 
So here we need to make a humanbeing from our category which we have described above , so how do we do that in Java

```
class Birth{
  public static void main(String [] args){
    HumanBeing firstHuman = new HumanBeing("Adam",25,6.2,90);    
  }
}
```

Now in the above example we have created our first human being with name age height weight , so what exactly is happening in the above code? . We are **Instantiating** our category **HumanBeing** i.e An Object of our class is created

> **Note :** **Object and Instance are not Synonyms** In some cases it seems like Object and Instance are Synonyms but they are not, I will give both cases

**Case 1: Object and Instance seems to be Synonyms**
Let me elaborate a bit , when we say `HumanBeing firstHuman = new HumanBeing("Adam",25,6.2,90);` **An Object** of our category is created on the **heap memory** and some address is allocated to it , and `firstHuman` holds a reference to that address, now this Object is **An Object of HumanBeing** and also **An Instance of HumanBeing**.
Here it seems like Objects and Instance are Synonyms,**I will repeat myself they are not synonyms**

Let Us Resume our Story , we have created our firstHuman , now we can ask his name,age,height,weight , this is how we do it in Java

```
class Birth{
  public static void main(String [] args){
    HumanBeing firstHuman = new HumanBeing("Adam",25,6.2,90);
    System.out.println(firstHuman.getName());
    System.out.println(firstHuman.getAge());
    ...
    ...  
  }
}
```

so we have first human being and lets move feather by give our first human being some qualification ,let's make him a Doctor , so we need a category called **Doctor** and give our Doctor some behaviour ,so in java we do as follows

```
class Doctor extends HumanBeing{
   public Doctor(String Name,int Age,float Height,float Weight){
      super(Name,Age,Height,Weight);
   }
   public void doOperation(){
    /* Do some Operation*/ 
   }

   public void doConsultation(){
    /* Do so Consultation*/
   }
}
```

Here we have used the concept of **Inheritance** which is bringing some reusability in the code , Every Doctor will always be a HumanBeing first , so A Doctor will have Name,Age,Weight,Height which will be Inherited from HumanBeing instead of writing it again , note that we have just written a description of a doctor we have not yet created one , so let us create a Doctor in our `class Birth`

```
class Birth{
  public static void main(String [] args){
    Doctor firstDoctor = new Doctor("Strange",40,6,80);
    .......
    .......
    /*Assume some method calls , use of behaviour*/
    .......
    .......    
  }
}
```

**Case 2: Object and Instance are not Synonyms**
In the above code we can visualise that we are **Instantiating our category Doctor and bringing it to life** i.e we are simply creating an **Object of the category Doctor** , As we already know **Object are created on Heap Memory** and `firstDoctor` holds a reference to that Object on the heap ;

This particular Object `firstDoctor` is as follows (please note `firstDoctor` holds a reference to the object , it is not the object itself)

1. `firstDoctor` is **An Object of `class Doctor`** And **An Instance of A `class Doctor`**
2. `firstDoctor` is **Not An Object of `class HumanBeing`** But **An Instance of `class HumanBeing`**

So a particular Object can be an instance to a particular class but it need not be an object of that given class

**Conclusion:**

> An Object is said to be an Instance of a particular Category if it satisfies all the characteristic of that particular Category

Real world example will be as follows , we are first born as Humans so image us as Object of Human , now when we grow up we take up responsibilities and learn new skills and play different roles in life example Son, brother,  a daughter, father ,mother now What are we actually?We can say that we are Objects of Human But Instances of Brother,daughter,...,etc

I hope this helps

Thank You

Comment: ...and why do we have only 3 upvotes on this answer?

Comment: Thanks for the awesome explanation - is it your common understanding or is there an actual documented theoretical reference for this explanation just to make it official?

Comment: @hard_working_ant Thank you, And I am not aware of any actual documentation, I got this understanding from my teacher, all I tried doing was to put it into a simple example

Answer (score 14):

[image]

Objects are things in memory while instances are things that reference to them. In the above pic:

- std(instance) -> Student Object (right)
- std1(instance) -> Student Object (left)
- std2(instance) -> Student Object (left)
- std3(instance) -> no object (null)

Comment: That is great.  I really like the fact that it gets low level.  I am going back and forth on whether I like this better than the analogy.  I think knowing the 2 together is what I *really* needed.  upvote, but not sure if I can give the answer to you because it's already been given to Joe.  Thank you, though.  This clears up a lot.

Comment: Well, so an instance is a pointer to an object ? (instance==variable with memory address?)

Comment: Truong, your answer is wrong and confusing. In fact an instance is an object derived from a base class object. Instance == object. This terminology is good explained for example in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2290422/what-is-the-difference-between-object-and-instance#2296182) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2290422/what-is-the-difference-between-object-and-instance#2291192) answer.

Comment: @jww: The image is a link to http://math.hws.edu/javanotes/c5/objectsInHeap.png which is now 404. Presumably it was visible at the time it was posted.

Answer (score 7):

An object is an instance of a class (for class based languages).

I think this is the simplest explanation I can come up with.

Comment: I agree that your explanation is about right with the way I have been reading, but there are a lot of entries online that make a distinction between the two.  I don't know if this kind of question can't be answered without a language in mind (wow a meta-question, this question is a class that can't be used without instantiating it with a language, lol).

Answer (score 6):

A class defines an object.  You can go even further in many languages and say an interface defines common attributes and methods between objects.

An object is something that **can** represent something in the real world.  When you want the object to **actually** represent something in the real world that object must be instantiated.  Instantiation means you must define the characteristics (attributes) of this specific object, usually through a constructor.

Once you have defined these characteristics you now have an instance of an object.

Hope this clears things up.

Comment: I think that's basically saying what Joe said.  Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Above Joe says all houses built from the blueprint are objects. True.  And he says a given house is an instance.  True.  But, all the houses are instances and a given house is an object as well.  He was making a difference where there was none.  In code it is necessary to differentiate between an object and an instance at the moment we construct it.  We say it is instantiated when it's actually been built.  A common question might be:  Did you remember to instantiate the object? ie. if you forgot to call the constructor after you declared an object.

Comment: ah, that's a good distinction.  So to say it another way, an instance is an object that has been constructed (ie, had the constructor called).

Answer (score 3):

### What is an Object ?

An object is an instance of a class. Object can best be understood by finding real world examples around you. You desk, your laptop, your car all are good real world examples of an object.

Real world object share two characteristics, they all have state and behaviour. Humans are also a good example of an object, We humans have state/attributes - name, height, weight and behavior - walk, run, talk, sleep, code :P.

### What is a Class ?

A class is a blueprint or a template that describes the details of an object. These details are viz

name
attributes/state
operations/methods

```
class Car 
{
    int speed = 0;
    int gear = 1;

    void changeGear(int newGear)
    {
        gear = newGear;
    }

    void speedUp(int increment) 
    {
        speed = speed + increment;
    }

    void applyBrakes(int decrement) 
    {
        speed = speed - decrement;
    }
}
```

Consider the above example, the fields `speed` and `gear` will represent the state of the object, and methods `changeGear`, `speedUp` and `applyBrakes` define the behaviour of the Car object with the outside world.

#### References:

- [What is an Object ?](http://careerbaba.in/question/what-is-an-object/)
- [What is a Class ?](http://careerbaba.in/question/what-is-a-class/)

Answer (score 3):

"A class describes a set of objects called its instances." - The Xerox learning Research Group, "The Smalltalk-80 System", Byte Magazine Volume 06 Number 08, p39, 1981.

Answer (score 1):

I think that it is important to point out that there are generally two things. The blueprint and the copies. People tend to name these different things; classes, objects, instances are just some of the names that people use for them. The important thing is that there is the blueprint and copies of it - regardless of the names for them. If you already have the understanding for these two, just avoid the other things that are confusing you.

Answer (score 0):

Lets compare apples to apples. We all know what an apple is. What it looks like. What it tastes like. That is a class. It is the definition of a thing. It is what we know about a thing.

Now go find an apple. That is an instance. We can see it. We can taste it. We can do things with it. It is what we have.

Class = What we know about something. A definition.

Object/Instance = Something that fits that definition that we have and can do things with.

Answer (score 0):

In some cases, the term "object" may be used to describe an instance, but in other cases it's used to describe a *reference to* an instance.  The term "instance" only refers to the actual instance.

For example, a List may be described as a collection of objects, but what it actually holds are references to object instances.

Comment: So in this case, a reference is just a place-holder that contains a link to the instance?  Where a link could be something like a memory address?

Answer (score 0):

I have always liked the idea that equals the definition of a class as that of an ["Abstract Data Type"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_data_type). That is, when you defined a class you're are defining a new type of "something", his data type representation, in terms of primitives and other "somethings", and his behavior in terms of functions and/or methods. (Sorry for the generality and formalism)

Whenever you defined a class you open a new **possibility** for defining certain entities with its properties and behavior, when you instantiate and/or create a particular object out of it you're actually **materializing** that possibility.

Sometimes the terms object and instances are interchangeable. Some OOP purists will maintain that everything is an object, I will not complain, but in the real OOP world, we developers use two concepts:

1. Class: Abstract Data Type sample from which you can derive other ADT and create objects.
2. Objects: Also called instances, represents particular examples of the data structures and functions represented by a given Abstract Data Type.

Answer (score 0):

Object Oriented Programming is a [system metaphor](http://www.extremeprogramming.org/rules/metaphor.html) that helps you organize the knowledge your program needs to handle, in a way that will make it easier for you to develop your program. When you choose to program using OOP you pick up your OOP-Googles, and you decide that you will see the problem of the real world as many objects collaborating between themselves, by sending messages. Instead of seeing a Guy driving a Car you see a Guy sending a message to the car indicating what he wants the car to do. The car is a big object, and will respond to that message by sending a message to it's engine or it's wheel to be able to respond properly to what the Driver told him to do in the message, etc...

After you've created your system metaphor, and you are seeing all the reality as objects sending messages, you decide to put all the things your are seeing that are relevant to your problem domain in the PC. There you notice that there are a lot of Guys driving different cards, and it's senseless to program the behavior of each one of them separately because they all behave in the same way... So you can say two things:

- All those guys behave in the same way, so I'll create a class called
  Driver that will specify who all the Drivers in the world behave,
  because they all behave in the same way. (And your are using class based OOP)
- Or your could say Hey! The second Driver behaves in the same way as the first Driver, except he likes going a little faster. And the third Driver behaves in the same way as the first Driver, except he likes zigzagging when he drives. (And you use prototype based OOP).

Then you start putting in the computer the information of how all the Drivers behave (or how the first driver behave, and how the second and third differ from that one), and after a while you have your program, and you use the code to create three drivers that are the model you are using inside that PC to refeer to the drivers you saw in the real world. Those 3 drivers that you created inside the PC are instances of either the prototype ( actually the first one is the prototype, the first one might be the prototype himself depending on how you model things) or the class that you created.
The difference between instance and object is that object is the metaphor you use in the real world. You choose to see the guy and the car as objects (It would be incorrect to say that you see them as instances) collaborating between themselves. And then you use it as inspiration to create your code. The instance only exists in your program, after you've created the prototype or the class. The "objects" exist outside the PC because its the mapping you use to unite the real world with the program. It unites the Guy with the instance of Driver you created in the PC. So object and instance are extremely related, but they are not exactly the same (an instance is a "leg" of an object in the program, and the other "leg" is in the real world).

Answer (score 0):

I guess the best answer has already been given away.

Classes are blueprints, and objects are buildings or examples of that blueprint did the trick for me as well.

Sometimes, I'd like to think that classes are templates (like in MS Word), while objects are the documents that use the template.

Answer (score 0):

Extending one of the earlier given examples in this thread...

Consider a scenario - There is a requirement that 5 houses need to be built in a neighbourhood for residential purposes. All 5 houses share a common construction architecture.
The construction architecture is a ***class***.
House is an ***object***. 
Each house with people staying in it is an ***instance***.