# why do we use application context in sms manager in android

Tags: android

Why do we use Application context in sms Manager while we are Using Intent.What is the role which played application context in sms manager.please tell me...
 String no=mobileno.getText().toString();
                String msg=message.getText().toString();

```
            //Getting intent and PendingIntent instance  
            Intent intent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class);  
            PendingIntent pi=PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0, intent,0);  

            //Get the SmsManager instance and call the sendTextMessage method to send message  
            SmsManager sms=SmsManager.getDefault();  
            sms.sendTextMessage(no, null, msg, pi,null);  

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Message Sent successfully!",  
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why do we use Application context in sms Manager while we are Using Intent

You do not have to. In this case, `this` should be just fine for the places you are using `getApplicationContext()`.

[This blog post by Dave Smith](http://www.doubleencore.com/2013/06/context/) explains the roles of different contexts.

> What is the role which played application context in sms manager.

The `Application` `Context` has nothing specific to do with `SmsManager`, or `Toast` for that matter.

Comment: Then again why do we use mainactivity.class we can write mainactivity.this instead of application context and mainactivity.class.

Comment: @SaikiranRaju: `MainActivity.this` is an instance of an `Activity` (presumably, given the class name). `MainActivity.class` is an instance of a `Class` object. The `Intent` constructor that you are using takes a `Class` object as the second parameter, identifying the component (activity, service, etc.) for which the `Intent` is intended.

Comment: Instance means here the mainactivity it is an member variable of activity??

Comment: @SaikiranRaju: "Instance" here means "instance". http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5126082/what-exactly-is-an-instance-in-java