# Something about System.out.println

Tags: java

The text book has it mentioned as:

> System.out -> Class
>
> Println -> Method

But, I disagree.

I think it's:

> System -> Class
>
> Out -> Method

Now, according to my logic, should Println be a method inside the method (Out)?

What is the correct concept here?

Comment: `println` is a method of the `out` field of `System`.

Comment: field? Like a data member or a member method?

Comment: @Grendan: "field" is the Java term for a data member. In this case, it's a static field (a class data member).

Comment: But, data members can either be variables or methods, right?

Comment: @Grendan: No, that's what the "data" in "data member" is saying, that it's data, not a method. Java avoids the confusion by using "field" and "method".

Comment: @Grendan did I answer your question or do you have another question?

Answer (score 1):

`System.out` isn't a class or a method, it's a *static field* on the [`System` class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html) that is a *reference* to an *instance* of a class ([`PrintStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html)). [`println`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#println--) is an instance method of `PrintStream` (or more completely, `println` is the common name shared by a group of instance methods that are overloaded with different arguments).

Comment: Wait. It's take it one step at a time here. So, is `System.out` a static field of the `System` class or is `out` a static field of the `System` class. I think the latter but you say the former.

Comment: @Grendan: Those are the same thing, it's just that I partially-qualified the name (`System.out`) and you're using the unqualified name (`out`); it's the same field regardless. Or one could go whole-hog and *fully* qualify the name and say "`java.lang.System.out` is a static field of the `java.lang.System` class..."

Comment: I see. Thank you. Can you please explain how it's a reference to an instance of the `PrintStream` class please?

Comment: @Grendan: Continue with your Java learning and the terms "instance" and such will become clear to you. It's far too large a topic to go into in an SO answer. Or possibly not, as [there seem to be useful answers to "What exactly is an instance?"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5126082/what-exactly-is-an-instance-in-java).

Comment: Actually, I do know what an instance is and all that. In fact, I just finished inheritance. I'm good with the basics. Just that we've been using System.out.println all the time without understanding what's going on behind the scenes. That's why I asked.

Comment: What is the relationship between the System class and the PrintStream class?

Comment: @Grendan: Pretty much the `out` and `err` fields. That is, the `System` *uses* the `PrintStream` class.

Answer (score 0):

System is a class. Out is an object (public static final PrintStream out). println and print are methods. Trust the textbook.

[Proof](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html)

Comment: I disagree. If System is a class and out is an Object, System.out makes no sense.

Comment: Out is an instance of PrintStream. Here is the hierarchy. System is a class. System has an instance (object) called Out of PrintStream The PrintStream class has a method called print() and println(). You can call those through System.out.println(); I realize that this is new and you likely don't understand yet, but once you get into more difficult OOP you will understand the class structure better. For now trust all of the people on here telling you the correct answer (and the official Java documentation I posted).

Answer (score 0):

Methods cannot contain other methods, plus "out" never has any parentheses or takes any arguments, so "out" cannot be a method.