# Instace of class and object of class in java

Tags: java, instance

There can only be one instance of class and can have many objects...? If not then can you please explain me difference between Instance and Object of the class

Comment: An Object is an instance of a Class.  You can think of the object as the thing and "instance" as the relationship.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Difference between object and instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3323330/difference-between-object-and-instance)

Comment: Read this: [The Java Tutorials: Object Oriented Programming concepts](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/index.html)... and also read [this article](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: In other languages, objects can exist without an associated class.  In this case there is objects without instances.  In Java, all objects must be instances of a class.

Answer (score 0):

`Instance` and `object` of class are same things.

Theoratically  Instance represents certain object  at one time.

Example:  Suppose you have `Employee Class`(**Structure**) with `firstName` and `lastName`

your `instance or object`(**Value**) represent  Employee with firstname "Sanjay" and lastname "Rabari"