# Instance vs Object : The unclear debate

Tags: java, object, instance

In Java, what is the difference between instance of a class and Object of a class.

For a class A, Take a look :

line 1 : A a;  // Declaring a reference variable of class A

Line 2 :  a = new A();// Instantiating an object of class A ( An object/instance is created
                       on Right hand side of the equation)

So....can the line 2 also be : // Instantiating an instance of class A

which mean Instance and Object are absolutely the same thing ?

Please give an objective answer than subjective.

.So an instance and object is same ? No difference at all. An object is an instance of the class .... or an Instance is an object of a class....both are same ?

Comment: Please stop [reposting this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3323330/difference-between-object-and-instance).

Answer (score 1):

For all intents and purposes, object and instance can be used interchangeably, but the accepted answer at this link will give you a good understanding of how you ***should*** use the two:
[Difference between object and instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3323330/difference-between-object-and-instance)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I'd agree that "instance" and Object are the same thing.

```
1 : A a; // Declaring a reference variable of class A
2 : a = new A();// Instantiating an object of class A
3 : Object o = a;  // a is also an object
```

All instances in Java are also Objects, so they're the same thing.  That's an is-a relationship.  You can say that any instance in Java is-a Object.  Objects are a type (class), and you can make instances of just type Object alone if you want.

```
Object x = new Object();
```

Classes are also objects.

```
4 : Class<A> atype = a.getClass();
5 : Object otype = atype;
```

So objects (instances) have-a Class, and classes are objects too.  I think this is why things are so murky, all these words bear a very close relationship.  Note all the things on the left hand side are also called reference types.

Comment: None of the things on the left-hand side of your examples are primitives. Primitives are special data types: the built-in types like `int`, `byte`, `char`, etc; they're [not objects or subclasses of `Object`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html).

Comment: Hmm, apparently references aren't primitives.  I'm a little shocked, since they work exactly like primitives, but the Java specification makes them distinct.  I'll amend my answer.

Comment: Well, to say they work "exactly like primitives" is, I think, a bit of an oversimplification. You can declare a variable to be either a primitive _or_ a reference type. You can create a new reference type (by writing a new class), but you can't create a new primitive. Primitives also don't support methods; you can't say `int a = 3; a.plus(3);`

Comment: primitives use operators. `int i = 0; i + 3` for example.  So do reference types: `atype == otype`.  primitives have values, so do references: null, or the value returned by the "new" operator.  Java always passes both by value in a method argument.  That primitives don't support methods might be considered a mistake in the language. :)

Comment: Using `==` on two reference types is comparing equality using the JVM hashcode (ie, a primitive); it's almost always preferable to use `.equals()`. Reference types only support a limited subset of operators; you can't overload the arithmetic or bitwise operators to work on reference types like you can with C++ objects. Objects (reference types) are not passed by value into a method; rather, the _references_ to those objects are passed by value. It's [a subtle distinction](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value).

Comment: PS: I'm not trying to sound argumentative or pedantic; I just think these are important distinctions, especially if anyone stumbles across this in the future (unlikely, since the question is dying the death of a dupe...).