# Difference between object and instance

Tags: c#, oop

I am studying C# and I am a little confused with the terminology... I saw that there are still many same questions like this but i am still confused... Can someone explain me the difference between an object and an instance?

Comment: It's just a matter of semantics, really.  Depends on the context of what you're talking about.  Without context, the terms are pretty much interchangeable.  Is there some specific text or example in which they're meant to be different?  One *might* use "object" in a *slightly* more generic way when saying, for example, "`x` is an instance of a `Widget` object."

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between object and instance](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3323330/difference-between-object-and-instance)

Comment: Not exactly... I need it as a general meaning, since they are used frequently in programming terminology

Comment: @whatever123456 And their meaning is contextual.  There is no one single definition, so you either need to provide a context, or you can't get a meaningful (correct) answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The words *object* and *instance* basically refer to the same thing.

In object oriented programming there is the concept of classes. You can basically *do nothing* without a class.

A class is the *blueprint* for creating an object (classes marked as static, abstract etc. are excluded from this statement.), with specific characteristics  and behaviour defined in the class. An object can be also called an instance of a class.

For example:

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

The above is a class. It just defines a type called `Person` with two properties  `Name` and `Age`.

When you need a person object (or an instance of this class), you can create it using the `new` operator and an appropriate constructor (below I use an object initializer).

```
var person = new Person 
{ 
    Name = "Foo",
    Age = 30
};
```

Now the `person` is an object or equivalently an instance of the class `Person`.

Comment: so basically an object and an instance of a class is the same thing?

Comment: Exactly, they are the same thing !

Comment: static classes still inherit from System.Object.  That's where I'm still not sold

Comment: @Jonesopolis Every type in .NET has as it's base type the `System.Object`. Actually, you can think of a static class as an object which has been created automatically by the runtime on the loading of your application, but no other type can be created based on the class used to create this object. There would be only one object with the specifed behaviour in your app. *Beware*  this is an analogy I tried to use to explain it. Regarding the term instance in this context, I think it's meaningless. You can't say I have an instance of a static class...What's the point?

Answer (score 2):

This is only terminology, and common usage.  The word *object* is used, generally to refer to the thing that is created in memory, and referenced or represented by a variable in your code, when you create a data structure based on a class.  The word *instance* means exactly the same thing, but is used when the emphasis is on the fact that a specific *object* is but one of many *object*s that may have been or could be created from that class.  i.e., an *object* created from class `MyClass` is but one *instance* of `myClass`.

Comment: This description falls down a bit in the case where you have several instances of the class ```object``` as here instance and object are not interchangeable. Objects are "things" like "people", where as an in this analogy an instance would be an individual "person". As all "things" derive from ```object```, people can still be objects, but a person is an instance of an object, not an object.

Comment: I'm not clear as to what your point is. Are you discussing the scenario where someone creates a custom class and names it `object` ? I'm not sure that is even possible. I think not.  Or are you referring  to the built-in .Net class object that is the root of the class hierarchy? If that is the case, then, technically, ***every*** `instance` (of anything, not just of a `person`) is indeed an `object`, just as every `moose` is indeed an `animal`.