# What are differents between DBLogHelper.instance and DBLogHelper() in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

The Code A use `DBLogHelper.instance` to initial `mDBLogHelper`, and Code B use `DBLogHelper()` to initial `mDBLogHelper`.

What are differents, which one is the better?

**Code A**

```
class DBLogHandler(private val mDBLogHelper: DBLogHelper =DBLogHelper.instance) {
}
```

**Code B**

```
class DBLogHandler(private val mDBLogHelper: DBLogHelper =DBLogHelper()) {
}
```

**Code For Both**

```
class DBLogHelper(mContext: Context = UIApp.instance) : ManagedSQLiteOpenHelper(
        mContext,
        DB_NAME,
        null,
        DB_VERSION) {

    companion object {
        val DB_NAME = "log.db"
        val DB_VERSION = 1
        val instance by lazy { DBLogHelper() }
    }

    override fun onCreate(db: SQLiteDatabase) {
       ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3323330/difference-between-object-and-instance

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2885385/what-is-the-difference-between-an-instance-and-an-object

Comment: `.instance` will create only one instance while the other will create a new one each time