# Is there a difference between an Instance and an Object in C#?

Tags: c#, class, oop, object, instance

I'm studying the OOP aspect of C# and I would like to know if there is a difference between and Instance and an Object?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between object and instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3323330/difference-between-object-and-instance)

Comment: _Instance_ and _class_ are the two relevant terms (like cake and recipe) - _Object_ can be used to mean either. - In terms of syntax, _object_ is a type like _int_ or _string_..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're reading a *book*, I'd bet the main meaning of "object" would be "an instance of a class".

Sometimes, it could refer to the class itself, as an over-simplification.

(and as @TaW noticed in comments, it could also be the *keyword* `object`, which is an alias for `System.Object`, and which is a type in C#).

It depends on context, don't try to match words to exact and frozen meanings.

Imagine this sentence:

*"A car is red"* -> "car" is probably talking about one car in particular. ("Down the road, a car is red, and another is blue."). --> **instance**

*"A car has 4 wheels"* -> "car" is probably referring to all cars. ("In general, a car has 4 wheels.") -> **class**.

You can probably tell by the context which is which. But if this is not the case, you need to show us some more precise example so we can help you more.